# Regular expression that match letters from all language php

Tags: php, regex, expression

im trying for few hours to find the right regular expression in php to match any language letters but to prevent it to allow space

i have try this

```
[^\p{L}]
```

this is ok but it look like it allow the space

then i have try this

```
[^\w_-]
```

and it still look that it allow space

anyone can help with this please ?

Comment: Hi @mireille28 and thanks for asking your question on StackOverflow. I just wanted to provide you with some helpful tips for the future. You should always remember to provide the input you tried and the result you got that you didn't expect to get in your question so that people know where you went wrong. Please also review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to get better answers in the future.

Comment: thanks Sherif im still a little bit confuse with this site will try to improve my question in future thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the Unicode modifier `u` to get [Unicode character properties in PCRE](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode).

*For example...*

```
$pattern = "/([\p{L}]+)/u";
$string  = "你好，世界！Привет мир! !مرحبا بالعالم";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $match)) {
    var_dump($match);
}
```

Gives us...

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "你好"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "世界"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "Привет"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "мир"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "مرحبا"
    [5]=>
    string(14) "بالعالم"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "你好"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "世界"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "Привет"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "мир"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "مرحبا"
    [5]=>
    string(14) "بالعالم"
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, yes the u is working but this still allow the space what i do not want to allow that is where i stuck

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*allow the space*" exactly. There are no spaces, as you can clearly see, in the captured patterns as illustrated in the example above.

Comment: as example i want my user to be able to register with all language but when i use /([\p{L}]+)/u as you mentionned if a user put a space in his username choice it will still pass the verification i want in final to allow all characters but prevent users to put a space in

Comment: OK, you definitely didn't make any of that clear from your question. Your question title states ***Regular expression that match letters from all language php*** which is definitely not what you're trying to do here. You're trying to match white space characters to validate that the string does not contain any white space. So instead you want to use the [whitespace character class](http://php.net/regexp.reference.character-classes) `\s` to ensure the string does not contain any white space characters.

Comment: finally i solved my problem using your regular expression and making a second preg_match validation that check to be sure the name is not containing a space i should have think of the second preg_match earlier my bad

Comment: @Mireille28 Reads like you want to add [start and end](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) anchors: [`/^\pL+$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/vN1uM2/1)